# How to publish Android application with different accounts

Tags: android, google-play, google-account

I register and buy an android market account and publish the application. But now I want to publish it using another account. Is there any easy way to transfer my published application from A account to B?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can't just unpublish it with account A and then publish the same APK with account B. The key that you use to sign the apk is what the market uses to determine if it is the same app. So your users should still get update notices. The only side effect of this that I can think of is that your app downloads counter will reset to 0. I have not done this before but I see no reason it wouldn't work

Comment: thanks, I sent email to android market. They suggest to register another android account. And then, they will help to transfer the application and refund the previous account registration fee.